# RegExp to match @Tag

Tags: regex

I want to implement a Tag system in my application. Something like @User1 will output `<a href="#">@User1</a>`

I know how to do it with something like [tag]User1[/tag], but i don't like a BBCode style.
I tried something like this: `preg_match_all('/@(.*)[\s|\S]/', $str, $matches);` but it doesn't work.

Any suggestion?
Thanks for you help

Solution:

`preg_match_all('/@(.+?)\b/', $str, $matches);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@(.*)[\s|\S]` will match *everything* up to the very last non-space, space, or pipe character (which is everything).  I believe you want to use

```
@(.+?)\b
```

This will match every character up to the first word boundary (because of the `?`, reluctant quantifier).  `.+` is also used because there probably has to be at least one character in the username.